# $\ln (2)$ from Taylor series with error at most $10^{-5}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

How do I calculate $\ln (2)$ by Taylor series with error at most $10^{-5}$?

I use Maclaurin:
$$
\frac{(1+c)^{-(n+1)}\cdot {{(-1)}^n}}{n+1}<\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n+1}<10^{-5}
$$
$n=10^{-5}$

Where did I go wrong?
Thanks

Comment: The series for $\ln(2) = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \ldots$ is alternating so the error by including $n$ terms is less than the $(n+1)$'th term. The (one of the) error(s) you have done is $\frac{1}{n+1} < 10^{-5}$ implies $n+1 > 10^{5}$ not $10^{-5}$. Also: you should use absolute values in the inequalities you have.

Comment: i know.. but in order to find ln2 i have to put n=10^-5